# flutter_platform_widgets preventing build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, nullable, flutter-packages

I was working on my Flutter application and was not having any problems. When I was finished, I ran flutter upgrade as a new version was available. my first time attempting to run since the upgrade, the application fails to build and I get the following error.
"Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-2.2.6/lib/src/platform.dart:294:29: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max."

I tried upgrading my flutter_platform_widgets but it would not upgrade to 3.0.0. I tried downgrading flutter but that also failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As manually you can delete this error cache from the finder.

Example:
`Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets 2.2.6/lib/src/platform.dart:294:29: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.`

Go along that directory and find in `home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev....` and delete that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **flutter_platform_widgets** is at least **version 3** in your pubspec.yaml then run flutter pub upgrade.